# Rails 4 Object.reload removes all the accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

using Rails 4.1.5 And ruby 2.1.2p95

User has one location.

in user model, I've code like:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for location
```

for some reason, After User.save in after_save callback, I've to use user.reload and want to update user posting in user model. like

```
user.reload.update_attribute('posting', 1111)
```

**Before Reload** when i check user.location it **gives the location**

**after reload -** it gives **blank value**. any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Not much to go on here... Is the location actually valid/saving?

Comment: location is a valid record. but reload removes its associated NEW RECORD from user.